# Magento: add static block above footer only for Product View pages?

Tags: magento, view, block, product

In Magento, how can I add a static block just above the footer, but only on Product View pages? I've got it partially working by modifying catalog.xml and page/html/footer.phtml - but it's showing on all pages, which is not what I am looking for.

Also I must be able to show it so it spans both columns on a 2-column layout.

Any ideas anyone?

Cheers,
Michael.

Comment: What do you mean when say "by modifying catalog.xml"? Do you use layout updates or you edit this file directly?

Comment: @Zyava it means I added:        `<reference name="footer">
            <block type="cms/block" name="disclaimer" as="disclaimer">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>disclaimer</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </reference>`

Comment: @Zyava and yes, I modified the file directly because I have a custom template...

Answer (score 1):

If you put it into the page template view.phtml file directly then you will not have this problem.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('macguffin')->toHtml() ; ?>
```

Where `macguffin` is your block.

You can also pull through your block title with a bit more code:

```
<?php $block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())    ->load('macguffin');
echo "<h3>".$block->getTitle()."</h3>"; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I already have tried that, but I need the block to span both main and right columns, exactly like the footer block does. If I add the block in the view (in my case the easytabs product view phtml), the block spans the width of the main column only. Michael.